# Associate Windows directory with program (or treat directory as file)

Tags: windows

This is likely not a simple topic - I have researched this to the best of my abilities and realize that it is not supported in any typical fashion.

My goal is to enable something similar to .app files from OSX, where the application, as well as its user data, can exist in the same file. I imagine it would require writing a tool to manage this behaviour, but this question is more about how to achieve this in the Windows OS.  I am quite flexible regarding the implementation details, but the more straightforward the behaviour, the better (i.e. avoiding copying or compressing/decompressing entire directories/archives at runtime would be ideal).

Approaches I have considered:

- Find a way to get explorer to treat a directory as a file, so that it can be associated.  I have found a way to get explorer to treat a directory as a control panel item, I have thus far been unable to find a way to use this to associate a custom program.  See the infamous "godmode hack" for Windows (name a directory something to the effect of "GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}").  This one seems the most hopeful, but I'm at wits end trying to find information about creating a new association of this type.
- Come up with some kind of archive format which can extract executable information to a temporary directory, launch this executable passing the archive as a commandline parameter.  This seems like the ugliest solution, from a performance perspective.  I would prefer a different solution if at all possible, one which doesn't involve making duplicates of the program or its data to run.
- Find a way to associate a directory directly, though I have found no trace of this being supported in Windows, and I assume this is a dead-end.
- Find a way to get an executable to include writeable embedded files.  I have been unable to make any headway with this- I even tried a resource hacker approach, but obviously you cannot modify the assembly while its in use.
- Tried to make a self-modifying JAR file with Java, but the route I took would add the JDK as a runtime requirement, which seems a bit overkill.  Even then, it would be limited to Java, and I'm pretty sure it's not actually supposed to allow that in the first place.
- Modify Windows Explorer. I shudder at the amount of work this would take, not to mention the at-best gray area it falls under legally. Perhaps there's a way to extend explorer to achieve this, I'm not sure.
- A custom archive file.  This seems like the most straightforward way to do it.  But it would ideally need to be an archive format that has very little overhead for file I/O. Could even be some kind of virtual disk that gets mounted, but I am imagining that would be pretty heavy.

I would appreciate any insight that anyone has on this topic.  I won't go into reasons as they are irrelevant to the question itself- I'm aware it is likely not the most practical solution to anything in particular. Consider it a novel pursuit.

Comment: Create a shell namespace extension and name the folder "whatever.{...}" where "{...}" is the CLSID for your shell namespace. Writing a shell namespace extension is a major undertaking, however, and "How do I write a shell namespace" is too broad a topic for SO. Specific questions about shell namespace extensions could work though.

Comment: I have accepted Micheal's answer below, as it seems to be the most proper way to go about this.  Thanks again Raymond, for the shell namespace extension comment, as that provides me with another important piece of the puzzle, displaying the virtual directory in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by application virtualization,
Read this wikipedia page theory:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_virtualization

And two pages about software:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ThinApp

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_(software)

Comment: Brief but effective - I do believe this is the best way to go about it. I am getting significantly better research results using these terms.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 added the ability for a Desktop.ini file to [add/change the folder verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171(v=VS.85).aspx#custom_verbs_desktop) on a per-folder basis. Using that trick it is possible to create a ["folders as applications" style setup](https://windowssucks.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/the-application-directory-bundle-shell-hack/).